# Is there a way to identify the reasons that led a user to abandon a journey inside an app in GoogleAnalytics/Data Studio?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm working on an app that, according to user feedback, has a high frequency of errors on the login screen. I set up a dashboard in Data Studio to check the volume of users leaving the journey at the login screen and a little later. I can create a segment in Google Analytics to identify how many users accessed the app's Home, how many users made it through the Login screen, and how many successfully ended the journey. Of course, many users "get lost along the way", but I would like to know why these users don't finish the journey and specifically how many abandon the journey due to an app error.

Is there a way to identify the reasons that led a user to abandon a journey inside an app in Google Analytics/Data Studio?

Answer (score 0):

loot at hotjar https://www.hotjar.com/, im not affiliated, a front end dev (also systems admin) just showcased it for us and I really liked it! There are free alternatives, Matomo looked nifty.

It records the users mouse and typing events purely inside your page (no bookmarks or the address box in the browser for example, those are private).

It creates a heat-map for how far people scroll the page, what percent get how far, a heat map for clicks, but also user "stories" following a screen recording of each visitor. including mouse trace, where they seemed to get confused, sometimes you can see people are bored and click on things just for no reason lol. pretty fun! hope it helps